# How can I see phpmyadmin with XAMPP?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have installed XAMPP in a virtual machine with VirtualBox. I run both Apache and MySql and there aren't any errors.

I can access phpmyadmin from this virtual machine but if I try to run it on the real machine, I can't get it.

I tried to put http://IP of the virtual machine/phpmyadmin but it doesn't work.
If I put only http://IP of the virtual machine I can see a webpage in which it says "It works".

If I try to use http://localhost in the virtual machine I can see a page in which I see "XAMPP" and where I can choose the language in which I want to use it.

I want to use phpmyadmin from real machine.

Comment: What OS is the server you are trying to run phpmyadmin on?

Comment: I just want to make a database for my application on Android. But I have XAMPP in Windows 7.

Comment: try localhost/phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I realized that I had installed Apache 2.4 in my real machine so the main page that I saw before and could see this: "It works" was from this Apache.

I solved it uninstalling Apache, and now it works perfectly.

Thanks all of you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

The screen you get is the real (splash) screen choose your language from there you will be routed to make the basic setup options, then you will see the phpmyadmin link under the subheading "Tools", select it and see what the link is for you

Comment: I tried to make that but I have a problem. I can see the webpage of phpmyadmin in my virtual machine but not in my host computer. There, it gives me the following error:  "Not Found

The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server."

Answer (score 0):

Create a host only network in virtualbox. Configure the network in your guest machine. Then using IP of guest in the host only network
try `http://IP/phpmyadmin` . It will work if you have installed it correctly.

Comment: It works in my virtual machine but not in my host computer. And I want to use my phpmyadmin from my host computer, not from my virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

as you are working on Windows you might have to configure your host file and allocate a different ip for your vm then add a new alias(or change your alias) in your http-xampp.conf